# Null checking inside where clause in Entity Framework Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a query that returns `null reference exception`. 
I'm filter data using searching, I put breakpoint and check that the problem is that when a column has a null value it returns `exception`.

**Controller**:

```
if (searchValue != null || searchValue != "")
{
     expheadlist = expheadlist.Where(e => 
                    e.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchValue) || 
                    e.Description.ToLower().Contains(searchValue) 
                    ).ToList<GenExpenseHead>();
}
```

I allowed null values in `Description` attribute. This entity has a null value in `Description` column. I think therefore it returns `NullException` in this code. I don't know how to resolve it.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use ...`e.Description?.ToLower`... the db can handle nulls, but c# can't call method on null reference. But it looks, that this is executed as linq to objects and not ef linq, should see how the source of this qury us prepared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot write `?.` (null conditional operator) and `??` (null coalescing operator) in `Where` clause.  Instead use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` in your query as follows:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchValue))
{
     expheadlist = expheadlist.Where(e => (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Name) || e.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchValue))
                    || (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Description) || e.Description.ToLower().Contains(searchValue))
                    ).ToList<GenExpenseHead>();
}
```

Moreover also simply your `searchValue != null || searchValue != ""` condition using `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` as I have used!

Comment: Has it worked for you?

Comment: What is the error showing it right now?

Comment: `only, call, increment, decrement, await and new object expressions can be used as a statement.`

Comment: Try removing the `?? false` from the `Name` and `Description` and let me know if it works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185775/discussion-between-huzaifa-and-tanvirarjel).

Answer (score 0):

one way to solve it would be using the `?.` (null propagation operator)  and `??` (null coalescing operator):

```
expheadlist = expheadlist.Where(e => 
                    e.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchValue) || 
                    e.Description?.ToLower().Contains(searchValue) ?? false
                    ).ToList<GenExpenseHead>();
```

This says if `Description` is `null` then return `false` preventing the exception otherwise call `.ToLower().Contains(searchValue)`

Comment: You  cannot write `?.` (null conditional operator) and `??` (null coalescing operator) in `Where` clause as you wrote. it will throw `only, call, increment, decrement, await and new object expressions can be used as a statement.` error.

Answer (score -1):

using ?. (null propagation operator) and ?? (null coalescing operator) for both fields such as

```
expheadlist = expheadlist.Where(e => 
                e.Name?.ToLower().Contains(searchValue) ?? false || 
                e.Description?.ToLower().Contains(searchValue) ?? false
                ).ToList<GenExpenseHead>();
```